# How to display checked out user name on notification email

Tags: workflow, email, check-out

I have set up an extremely basic Nintex workflow which simply sends an email on document change.

As part of the email I wish to include the name of the person who checked it out.
I have tried to insert references to both 'Document Checked Out User' and 'Checked Out To' but both turn up empty in the email. Related fields such as 'Checked In Comment' are displaying fine.

Can anyone explain how to get the name to display

Thanks

Comment: Which internal name are you using to reference the Checked Out User? The internal name is CheckoutUser and is of type User.

Comment: I am simply using the Nintix workflow builder. 'Checked Out User' is one of the properties available in the references dialog - So I don't directly access internal names - just select from a list

Comment: I believe this may be off-topic. As per site rules: *"We also accept questions about community-owned, open source products based on the platform. We don't accept questions about commercial products that integrate with, run on top of, or extend the platform."*